# How to use geb in groovy shell

Tags: groovy, gradle, geb

I just started working with *geb* and I enjoy it a lot!
My task is to write tests for websites.

My question is - can I use *gradle* to launch *groovy shell* (not console) to experiment with my scripts?

Why I want to do that?
Currently I use groovy console to write my scripts.
I have following lines in my *gradle.build*

```
task(console, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'groovy.ui.Console'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

*gradle console* launches my console and then I type something like.

```
import geb.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

def browser = new Browser(driver: new FirefoxDriver())

Browser.drive {
    go "http://mypage.com/"
    //do some stuff to login
    //do some stuff to reach specific page
    //do some stuff to reach the state I want
    doAssertion
}
```

Then I see that I made a mistake in *doAssertion* function, so I correct it and relaunch my script, but then I have to wait fo the browser to come, wait for logging to take place and wait for the rest of clicking to see that I have one more spelling mistake in my script.

I would like to know if there is a way to connect to the browser where it ended just before exception and continue tinkering with my script from there?

I have tried to find solution to this problem with no luck.

[EDIT]:
After talking with a friend we have found the solution.

*geb* creates one instance of *webDriver* and it uses it until we create new one. That means, that *Browser.drive* will continue from the same point if I delete line:

```
new Browser(driver: new FirefoxDriver())
```